# for jquery,is it necessary that our files need to be hosted in a server?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a small `html` page including `jquery`. I added some codes in to the `html` file and i cannot test the working of `jquery`. Is there is any need for web servers to run `jquery` ?

Comment: No, but you do need to post an error message for us to offer meaningful advice. Are you seeing anything on the console? Are you including `jquery.js` via a `<script>` tag? The only answer we can give to the question you ask is "No, you don't need a server".

Comment: Have you implemented the library? or you just added 'some jQ codes' to your html document?

Comment: You have to have jQuery library either on your machine (if you run locally) or your server

Comment: @bobek or faster solution is to load it from **Google API code libraries**.

Comment: @roXon if that is your preference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is any need for web servers to run jQuery?

No. See [How jQuery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery runs on the client side so simple answer is no.  The web servers don't run the jQuery but you might have the library file hosted on your server.  Just include it in your script where your running the jQuery.

```
<!-- scr points to the path on the server-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or you could point to it from google api

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think they forgot to implement the library! : *"...I added some codes"*

Answer (score 0):

> for jquery,is it necessary that our files need to be hosted in a server?

Yes, if you intend to use it. You can either [download a copy](http://jquery.com/) or use a CDN, e.g. [Google's CDN for jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery). The advantage of a CDN is that a lot of people should already have it preloaded in their browsers / cache which could help decrease the size of your site and potentially decrease loading time of your page. Another advantage is that it'll almost always be the latest version of jQuery, so you won't have to manually update your own copy every time the next jQuery version comes out.

**Edit**

Here's a quick test you can do on your page to see if jQuery has been loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (jQuery) {  
    alert('jQuery is loaded');
} else {
    alert('jQuery is not loaded'); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic DOM-manipulation parts of jquery do not need a server. They're in-browser only. However, if you're using jquery for AJAX operations, then yes, you do need a server. Those require HTTP connections which cannot be done without involving a webserver of some sort.

Comment: do you know of a good resource that explains how to make this happen, for a rookie?